# How to set index type 'text' using mongodb compass?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am currently using mongodb compass, I want to create index with type 'text'. I followed steps given on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#single-field. However, I failed to create index with type 'text'. In compass GUI, dropdown titled 'Select a type' does not show type 'text' in it's dropdown. Am I missing  anything ?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Wondering the same thing. Is this only for the paid/subscription versions?

Comment: I think it is not possible through the interface... You can, *-as you already know for sure-* do `mongo`, `use [database]`, `db.[collection].ensureIndex({"field":"text"})`. Compass will show text indexes thou.

Comment: It's not currently implemented. Here is the ticket for it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-520

Comment: its so nice of mongo people not even mentioning that its not possible! no hint about it here: https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/indexes/

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug. And you can also provide the feedback on https://feedback.mongodb.com/ to fix this issue. depending upon the voting and the people like to fix this issue, the issue will be fixed in the future versions.

Comment: It would seem to be a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52235099/#comment102128340_52235099).